# How to sum the input field values and display it into html Table using Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

[image]

I am new to Javascript, Please help to me solve this issue Javascript experts.
I have a registration form that have these above fields. In this form, When I click "Add new registration line", it will insert new insert field like as above. From these, I want to add these hightlighted input fields values and display it in html table. When I check the checkbox, the values should be displayed in invoicable field, Likewise when I uncheck the checkbox, the values should be displayed in Non-Voicable field. I mean the sum of checked values should be displayed in Invoicable field and the sum of unchecked values should be displayed in Non-invoicable field.
This is the code part of the issue i am trying:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {
var i = 8 + 1;
$('input#add').click(function() {
//store in hidden value for total row
document.getElementById("consinvoice").value=i;

$("<span style='margin-left:126px;'>:&nbsp;<select name='RegistrationType_"+i+"' id='RegistrationType_"+i+"' onchange=\"register('Invoicable_"+i+"',this.value,ConsultancyHours_"+i+".value)\"><option value='CH'>Consultancy Hours</option><option value='LH'>Lunch Hours</option><option value='TH'>Transportation Hours</option><option value='OH'>Other Hours</option></select>&nbsp;<input name='ConsultancyHours_"+i+"' type='text' id='ConsultancyHours_"+i+"' size='5' onkeyup=\"invotable(this.id,this.value);\"  /><label for='Hourprice'> Std. Hourprice</label>&nbsp;<input name='Hourprice_"+i+"' type='text' id='Hourprice_"+i+"' size='5' />&nbsp;<label for='Hourprice'>- Discount Hourprice</label>&nbsp;<input name='Hourprice2_"+i+"' type='text' id='Hourprice2_"+i+"' size='5' /><br /><span style='margin-left:652px;'><input name='Invoicable_"+i+"' type='checkbox' id='Invoicable_"+i+"' checked='checked' onclick=\"register('Invoicable_"+i+"',RegistrationType_"+i+".value,ConsultancyHours_"+i+".value)\" /><label for='Invoicable'> Invoicable</label></span><br /></span>").appendTo('dd');
i++;
}); 
});  
</script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
//register('Invoicable_"+i+"',RegistrationType_"+i+".value,this.value);
function invotable(getid,getvalue){
var getinvoicetbl = 'invoice_cons';
var previnvoice = document.getElementById(getinvoicetbl).innerHTML;
var dgetid = getid.split("_"); 
var getcount = document.getElementById("consinvoice").value;
//alert(getcount);
totalterm =0;
for (j=8;j<=getcount;j++)
{
totalterm += parseInt(document.getElementById("ConsultancyHours_"+j).value);
//register('Invoicable_'+j,document.getElementById("RegistrationType_"+j).value,document.getElementById("ConsultancyHours_"+j).value);
}
document.getElementById(getinvoicetbl).innerHTML = totalterm;

}


function register(getvoice,gettype,getvalue){
//alert(getvoice);
var checkbox = document.getElementById(getvoice).checked;
var getinvoice = 'invoice_cons';
var getnovoice = 'ninvoice_cons';
switch (gettype)
{
case "CH":
        if(checkbox ==true){
        //alert("true");
        document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML)+parseInt(getvalue);
        document.getElementById("totinvoice").value = document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML;


        document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML = document.getElementById("totinvoice").value - getvalue;
        alert(document.getElementById("totinvoice").value);
        alert(document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML);
        } else {
                alert(document.getElementById("totinvoice").value);

        document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML = parseInt(getvalue);


        document.getElementById("totinvoice").value = document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML = document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML - getvalue;
        }
break;
case "LH":
        if(checkbox ==true ){
        //alert("true");
        document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML)+parseInt(getvalue);
        document.getElementById("totinvoice").value = document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML;


        document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML = document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML - getvalue;

        } else {
        document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoice_cons").value)+parseInt(getvalue);


        document.getElementById("totinvoice").value = document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML = document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML - getvalue;
        }
default:
        if(checkbox ==true){
        //alert("true");
        document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML)+parseInt(getvalue);
        document.getElementById("totinvoice").value = document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML;


        document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML = document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML - getvalue;

        } else {
        document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoice_cons").value)+parseInt(getvalue);


        document.getElementById("totinvoice").value = document.getElementById(getnovoice).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(getinvoice).innerHTML = document.getElementById("invoice_cons").innerHTML - getvalue;
        }
}
}
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="consinvoice" id="consinvoice" value="8" />
<input type="hidden" name="totinvoice" id="totinvoice" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="fromtinvoice" id="fromtinvoice" value="0" />
<td width="220">
<span id="insert_table">
<table class="" id="invtable" width="150" border="1">
<tr>
    <td align="right">
    </td>
    <td align="right"  style="padding-left:15px; padding-bottom:10px;">
        Invoicable
    </td>
    <td align="right" style="padding-left:15px; padding-bottom:10px;">
        Non-Invoicable
    </td>
    <td align="right" style="padding-left:15px; padding-bottom:10px;">
        Total
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">Consultancy</td>
    <td align="right" id="invoice_cons">-</td>
    <td align="right" id="ninvoice_cons">-</td>
    <td align="right" >-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">Transportation</td>
    <td align="right" id="invoice_trans">-</td>
    <td align="right" id="ninvoice_trans">-</td>
    <td align="right" >-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">Lunch</td>
    <td align="right" id="invoice_lun">-</td>
    <td align="right" id="ninvoice_lun">-</td>
    <td align="right" >-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">Total</td>
    <td align="right" id="invoice_tot">-</td>
    <td align="right" id="ninvoice_tot">-</td>
    <td align="right" >-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
</span>
</table>
<p>
<label for="RegistrationType">
    Type
</label>
<span style="margin-left:92px;">
:&nbsp;<select name="RegistrationType_8" id="RegistrationType_8" onchange="register('Invoicable_8',this.value,ConsultancyHours_8.value)">
<option value="CH">Consultancy Hours</option>
<option value="LH">Lunch Hours</option>
<option value="TH">Transportation Hours</option>
<option value="OH">Other Hours</option>
</select>
<input name="ConsultancyHours_8" type="text" id="ConsultancyHours_8" size="5" onkeyup="invotable(this.id,this.value); " />
<label for="Hourprice"> 
    Std. Hourprice
</label>
<input name="Hourprice_8" type="text" id="Hourprice_8" size="5" />
<label for="Hourprice">
    - Discount Hourprice
</label>
<input name="Hourprice2_8" type="text" id="Hourprice2_8" size="5" />
<input name="Invoicable_8" type="checkbox" id="Invoicable_8" onclick="register('Invoicable_8',RegistrationType_8.value,ConsultancyHours_8.value)" checked="checked" />
<label for="Invoicable">
    Invoicable
</label>
<dd id="insert_row">
</dd>
</span>
</p>
<p>
<span style="margin-left:132px;">
<input type="button" id="add"  value="Add new registration line" />
</span>
</p>
<div style="margin-left:324px;">
</div>
<br />
<p>
<span style="margin-left:132px;">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save registration" />
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Beautiful image. Please post the code too :)

Comment: +1 for the artistic effort at pseudo-code!

Comment: Do you use any library as for JavaScript?

Comment: no its pure js, not used any frameworks

Comment: You have over 20 `document.getElementById` calls in your code. Use an alias for crying out loud: `function id( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ); }`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas : Thanks for your tips. could you pleas solve this issue using your coding way, please refer my image for clarification.

Comment: You're using jQuery at least, and a jQuery solution would be trivial.

Comment: @ Dave L : yes I am using Jquery for Add new registration line. and using pure JS for input fields and table calculations. Table operations are JS only.

Comment: @user844271 Just so you know, jquery counts as a "framework" for javascript :-)

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem by doing some debugging of the Javascript.

Comment: +1 for your way of questioning?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to add new row dynamically and other function to calculate the hour by scaning the form, then when the window is loaded, call the add row function to start. There is the source code that I created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
body{margin:0}
body,th,td{font:16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
table{border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed}
th,td{white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden}
th{font-weight:700}
#invtable{width:500px;margin:10px auto;border:1px solid #000}
#invtable th, #invtable td{border:1px solid #000}
#registrationForm{width:100%}
#registrationForm td{text-align:center}
#registrationForm input[type="number"]{width:140px}
</style>
<table id="invtable" width="150">
<tr>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Invoicable</th>
<th>Non-Invoicable</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr id="consultancy">
<th>Consultancy</th>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr id="transportation">
<th>Transportation</th>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr id="lunch">
<th>Lunch</th>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr id="other">
<th>Other</th>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr id="total">
<th>Total</th>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="registrationForm"></table>
<p><input type="button" id="addNewRegistrationLine" value="Add new registration line"></p>
<p><input type="submit" id="saveRegistration" value="Save registration"></p>
<script>
var doc = document;
function calculateHour() {
  var registrationForm = doc.getElementById('registrationForm');
  var registrationFormRows = registrationForm.rows
  var typeValue = {'CH' : [0,0], 'LH' : [0,0], 'TH' : [0,0], 'OH' : [0,0]};
  for (var i = 0, registrationFormRowsLength = registrationFormRows.length, typeSelect, inputs, hourInput, isInvoicable; i < registrationFormRowsLength; ++i) {
    typeSelect = registrationFormRows[i].getElementsByTagName('SELECT')[0];
    inputs = registrationFormRows[i].getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    hourInput = inputs[0];
    isInvoicable = inputs[inputs.length - 1].checked ? 0 : 1;
    typeValue[typeSelect.value][isInvoicable] += hourInput.value - 0;
  }

  var total = [0, 0]

  var consultancyCells = doc.getElementById('consultancy').cells;
  consultancyCells[1].innerHTML = typeValue['CH'][0];
  total[0] += typeValue['CH'][0];
  consultancyCells[2].innerHTML = typeValue['CH'][1];
  total[1] += typeValue['CH'][1];
  consultancyCells[3].innerHTML = typeValue['CH'][0] + typeValue['CH'][1];

  var transportationCells = doc.getElementById('transportation').cells;
  transportationCells[1].innerHTML = typeValue['TH'][0];
  total[0] += typeValue['TH'][0];
  transportationCells[2].innerHTML = typeValue['TH'][1];
  total[1] += typeValue['TH'][1];
  transportationCells[3].innerHTML = typeValue['TH'][0] + typeValue['TH'][1];

  var lunchCells = doc.getElementById('lunch').cells;
  lunchCells[1].innerHTML = typeValue['LH'][0];
  total[0] += typeValue['LH'][0];
  lunchCells[2].innerHTML = typeValue['LH'][1];
  total[1] += typeValue['LH'][1];
  lunchCells[3].innerHTML = typeValue['LH'][0] + typeValue['LH'][1];

  var otherCells = doc.getElementById('other').cells;
  otherCells[1].innerHTML = typeValue['OH'][0];
  total[0] += typeValue['OH'][0];
  otherCells[2].innerHTML = typeValue['OH'][1];
  total[1] += typeValue['OH'][1];
  otherCells[3].innerHTML = typeValue['OH'][0] + typeValue['OH'][1];

  var totalCells = doc.getElementById('total').cells;
  totalCells[1].innerHTML = total[0];
  totalCells[2].innerHTML = total[1];
  totalCells[3].innerHTML = total[0] + total[1];
}

function addNewRegistrationLine() {
  var registrationForm = doc.getElementById('registrationForm');
  var row = registrationForm.insertRow(registrationForm.rows.length);
  var typeSelectCell = row.insertCell(0);
  var type = [['CH', 'Consultancy Hours'], ['LH', 'Lunch Hours'], ['TH', 'Transportation Hours'], ['OH', 'Other Hours']];
  var typeSelect = doc.createElement('SELECT');
  for (var i = 0, typeLength = type.length, option; i < typeLength; ++i) {
    option = doc.createElement('OPTION');
    option.value = type[i][0];
    option.innerHTML = type[i][1];
    typeSelect.appendChild(option);
  }
  typeSelect.onchange = calculateHour;
  var typeLabel = doc.createElement('LABEL');
  typeLabel.innerHTML = 'Type';
  typeLabel.appendChild(typeSelect);
  typeSelectCell.appendChild(typeLabel);
  var hourInput = doc.createElement('INPUT');
  hourInput.type = 'number';
  hourInput.onkeyup = calculateHour;
  typeSelectCell.appendChild(hourInput);
  var hourPriceInputCell = row.insertCell(1);
  var hourPriceInput = doc.createElement('INPUT');
  hourPriceInput.type = 'number';
  var hourPriceLabel = doc.createElement('LABEL');
  hourPriceLabel.innerHTML = 'Std. Hourprice';
  hourPriceLabel.appendChild(hourPriceInput);
  hourPriceInputCell.appendChild(hourPriceLabel);
  var discountInputCell = row.insertCell(2);
  var discountInput = doc.createElement('INPUT');
  discountInput.type = 'number';
  var discountLabel = doc.createElement('LABEL');
  discountLabel.innerHTML = '- Discount Hourprice';
  discountLabel.appendChild(discountInput);
  discountInputCell.appendChild(discountLabel);
  var invoicableCheckBoxCell = row.insertCell(3);
  var invoicableCheckBox = doc.createElement('INPUT');
  invoicableCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
  invoicableCheckBox.onclick = calculateHour;
  var invoicableLabel = doc.createElement('LABEL');
  invoicableLabel.appendChild(invoicableCheckBox);
  invoicableLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Invoicable');
  invoicableCheckBoxCell.appendChild(invoicableLabel);
}
doc.getElementById('addNewRegistrationLine').onclick = addNewRegistrationLine;
window.onload = function() {
  addNewRegistrationLine();
};
</script>
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/kb2Vs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

since it appears that you are using the [Jquery Framework](http://www.jquery.com) you can use the [template feature](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) which will allow you to use your javascript data and create html from it, I personally have not used it though.But since you also tagged this with PHP. Why not just do it in PHP?

For Example:

```
$formData[];
foreach($_POST AS $field => $value) {
   $formData[$field] = $value;   
}
```

Then all your data is in an array and much easier to work with. Just make sure to put in the form tag and use the `method=“post”` attribute.